# .NET Core & Webpack results in bad request

Tags: c#, webpack, .net-core

In development, my team and I are experiencing 400 Bad request, using Webpack Dev Middleware with .NET Core 2.1/2.2. Our SPA is unable to load as our main script file cannot be served, nor reload on change.

[Network tab screenshot in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJnAq.png)

Here is a repository which reproduces the same error and our configuration: https://github.com/jdebarochez/dotnet-webpack-hotreload-issue

If we remove `UseWebpackDevMiddleware` in the `Startup.cs` class, it would work fine though.

Has anyone experienced such issue or see anything wrong with this configuration? It used to work fine, until 2 weeks ago. We can't find anything wrong in our last commits.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrading to Node.js 8.12.0 solved my issue. I was using the version 11.x of Node.js. The 10.x LTS didn't work neither.

I thought about Node.js compatibility version while reading the WebpackDevMiddleware class. 
 I will open an issue on https://github.com/aspnet/aspnetcore